# Select value from drop-down list

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have populated a drop-down list with info from a database, and I now need to select the value to be used within a query, I understand that I need to use

```
var variable = $('#filter option:selected').val();
```

however how would I then use this variable within the query.

Select Statement php

```
$menu="
<select name='filter' id='filter'>          
". $options . "
</select>                           
<br>";
```

Query

```
$queryFilms = "SELECT EventName FROM eventsrush WHERE EventName = '".$variable.""; 
$resultFilms = $mysqli->query($queryFilms); 
$rowFilms = $resultFilms->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: You're mixing JavaScript and PHP.  They run in two completely different contexts.  In order to use the value in server-side PHP code, you need to send that value to the server somehow.  Are you posting a form to the server?  Making an AJAX call?

Comment: I not using ajax, im posting the form, however i need to use the selected value on the page of the current form

Comment: you should be able to just read that value in php with `$_POST['filter']`

Comment: wouldnt $_POST['filter'] only work if the query is made on the page where the form is going to be sent to.

Answer (score 1):

When the form posts to the server, the server-side code can get the selected value of the `select` element (assuming it's part of the form) like this:

```
$_POST['filter']
```

This corresponds to the `name` attribute of the `select` element in the form.

***Note:*** What you're *about* to do is *very bad*.  You're trying to concatenate the posted value directly into a SQL query and execute that query against the database.  This opens your code to what's called [SQL Injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  You'll want to (after you read that linked page) switch from using string-concatenated SQL statements to using some form of prepared statements.

The main point is to *never* trust data submitted from the client, and to *never* treat data as executable code.  By using that string in a SQL statement, you're treating it as code to be executed on the database.  You don't want users executing their own code on your server.  Prepared statements isolate the input as data, treating it as a string value and not as code.

Comment: even if i used prepare statement I still dont get a value from the dropdownlist.

Comment: @user3125462: Can you be more specific?  Is the value being posted to the server at all?  (You can check the post values in browser debugging tools.)  Is the `select` element a descendant of the `form` element being posted?

Comment: No the value isnt posted, as i want the value to be selected before i sumbit the form

Comment: @user3125462: It's not clear what you're saying at this point.  The sequence of events here would be that you present the user with the `select` list, the user chooses one and submits the form, the server-side code then has the chosen option and renders a page with updated information.  How are you deviating from this sequence of events?

Comment: When the user selects the value, it then should automatically fill out the input fields, before the form is send off. I think i should be using ajax along wiht jquery.

Comment: @user3125462: In that case you would write some JavaScript to make an AJAX request to a server-side resource, including the value (either a POST or a GET request would be fine), and respond with JSON data (instead of a web page) containing the information that the client-side code needs.  The server-side code is essentially the same, though.  You'd still access the value with `$_POST[]` or `$_GET[]`, query the database, and output the data.  There are lots of tutorials on AJAX and PHP to get you started on that.